# Is the Vanishing Rasengan more powerful than the regular Rasengan?

Tags: boruto

In the anime, Boruto creates a Lighting Release version of the Rasengan that has the feature of turning invisible. How about his power?

Is the Vanishing Rasengan more powerful than the regular Rasengan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on who is using the Rasengan.

Someone like Naruto or Minato can make the Rasengan of its normal size would generally have a stronger one, but someone like Boruto who doesn't have the chakra to make it's size correct may make a weaker one. It's safe to assume that someone who has completely mastered Rasengan and can make it of normal size would have a stronger Rasengan than Boruto's Vanishing Rasengan.

In Chapter 54 of Boruto, Borushiki stated that Vanishing Rasengan is too weak to be a mortal blow, but is very painful when hitting the vitals. A mastered Regular Rasengan is strong enough to be a mortal blow, and even stronger when hitting the vitals. Because of that, Regular Rasengan is probably stronger than Boruto's Vanishing Rasengan.

It's just a problem of Boruto's chakra compared to people who have mastered a normal Rasengan.

Answer (score 0):

It really just depends on how much energy(chakra) the user has, as the vanishing rasengan is an "invisible" rasengan, considering the user Boruto isn't as "strong" as naruto or minato or Jiraiya.
But if Naruto could use the vanishing Rasengan it will surely be stronger than the rasengan

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! While we all appreciate your contribution, it's better *not* to answer old questions when you have nothing to add to the already existing ones nor contradict. It's also better to include relevant sources/information in your answer.